# ComboBox WPF + ObservableCollection<>()

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

В общем есть ComboBox в который нужно передать значения через binding из ObservableCollection. Пробовал сделать так, но выводит "First.Model.Workers". Подскажите в чем проблема и как это исправить?

**.xaml**

```
<ComboBox Margin="100,10" Height="30" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workers}"/>
```

**.cs**

```
namespace First.Models
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Worker> _workers;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Workers = new ObservableCollection<Worker>()
            {
                new Worker {Name = "Сергей", Number = "+375(29)999-99-99", Pay = 5000},
                new Worker {Name = "Вячеслав", Number = "+375(29)888-88-88", Pay = 4000},
                new Worker {Name = "Франц", Number = "+375(29)777-77-77", Pay = 3000}
            };
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
        {
            get => _workers;
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _workers)) return;
                _workers = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Workers));
            }
        }
    }

    public class Worker
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int Pay { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема:

```
<ComboBox Margin="100,10" Height="30" Width="100" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Workers}"/>
```

Вы задали привязку коллекции на выделенный элемент, т.е. как пример результат выбора элемента пользователем.

Для того что бы вывести данные в `ComboBox` вам необходимо привязать коллекцию элементов на поле `ItemsSource`.

```
<ComboBox Margin="100,10" Height="30" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workers}"/>
```

Но, тут есть одно но, когда вы привяжите коллекцию, то в `ComboBox`'e вы увидите подобие: `First.Models.Worker`. Для того что бы вывести какие-то данные, вам необходимо будет задать для `ComboBox` `DataTemplate` о котором я надеюсь вы знаете.

Для решения проблемы вывода данных в каждый элемент `ComboBox` есть несколько решений, самое подходящее вы должны придумать сами.

1. Задать `DataTemplate` для элементов `ComboBox`
2. Переопределить метод `ToString()` класса `Worker`.
3. Написать свой контрол, который сможет без преобразований и всего подобного работать с вашими данными.

Самое простое это переопределение метода `ToString`:

```
public class Worker
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int Pay { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
         // Данные не являются такими как нужны вам, придумайте сами как хотите их выводить.
         return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", Name, Number, Pay);
    }
}
```

Задать `DataTemplate`, тут потребуется поработать с `xaml` `ComboBox`'a:

```
<ComboBox Margin="100,10" Height="30" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workers}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--[ Пример является примитивным и служит лишь для показа ]-->
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{0}, {1}, {2}">
                        <Binding Path="Name" />
                        <Binding Path="Number" />
                        <Binding Path="Pay" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Ну контрол для сего я не стану писать, это муторно и отнимает много времени.

Comment: Вместо DataTemplate можно просто переопределить ToString() класса.

Comment: Исправив на ItemsSource стало выводиться как вы и говорили, про DataTemplate не знаю ничего, недавно только начал осваивать WPF. Сейчас буду читать что это такое)

Comment: @Sanvirtus: Ответ изменен, надеюсь поможет =)

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался)

Answer (score 3):

Кроме ответа данного ヒミコ есть ещё способ: указать в атрибуте DisplayMemberPath имя свойства который вы хотите отобразить. Этот способ подходит если есть такое свойство у целевого объекта.

```xml
<ComboBox
   Margin="100,10"
   Height="30"
   Width="100"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Workers}"
   DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Резюмирую. Возможные способы решения:

1. Задать атрибут DisplayMemberPath. Подходит если есть соответствующее
   свойство.
2. Реализовать метод ToString в классе VM. Подходит, если строковое представление устраивает и метод ToString не занят для чего-то другого.
3. Задать ItemTemplate. Подходит в оставшихся случаях (не устраивает строковое представление, метод ToString используется для другого и его менять нельзя). С этим способом можно задать собственное представление: элементы управления, расположение, цвет, и т.д.
4. Создать свой контрол. Это тяжёлая артиллерия. В большинстве случаев это не нужно.